# How to find tablerow element containing a certain span element with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to write a method which takes a string variable (the name of a certain node) and gets the tr element containing an element with text same as the given string.

First step would be to find an element in my html with

```
element.text = string
```

But i cant get the the    XPath    expression for that.

I tried

```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//span[text()={0}]", &stringVariable)));
```

This code throws an exception "cannot be evaluated or does not result in a Webelement."

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

neither

```
//tr[span[text()= 'variableValue']]
```

nor

`//tr[span[contains(text(), 'variableValue')]]`

works whereas

```
//tr[contains(text(), 'partOfVariableValueUntilFirstSpace')]
```

will work. I cannot explain why...

Comment: Post the HTML of the table's contents. We are second guessing here.

Comment: okay i got it now... you have to replace every space with 'x0020'...

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that at all, again, without the HTML, we are second guessing. If your theory works, post it as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: I cant asnwer right now because of my reputation, i will do it on monday if i dont forget to...

Answer (score 1):

You can use following Xpath

```
//tr[span[text()='variableValue']]
```

It will find `tr` element which have a `span` element with text as variable value.

Comment: my variableValue has spaces in it, could this be a problem?

Comment: @user3292642: Dont think it will cause any problem.

Comment: neither text()= 'variableValue' nor [contains(text(), 'variableValue')] works whereas [contains(text(), partOfVariableValueUntilFirstSpace')] will work. I cannot explain why